# Searching for clarifications with jQuery/AJAX call in Safari/Mac (one more...)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load

Newbie here, I hope someone could help me to find a solution to a problem which only happens in `safari` mac.

I designed a site for a friend which use `CMS` made simple for the back-office and an `AJAX` load content function (she wanted a flash like website, it's a first try for me...).

```
http://marielaurebrunet.com/
```

Everything works fine in all browsers, but not in safari mac where my php news module doesn't load the new content when I click the title of the news... It's still the same page which is loaded.
The problem only occurs in the news section and only in safari mac.

FF, opera, IE works perfectly

Everything's ok in chrome. In safari mac:

```
"Failed to load resource: aborted"
```

every time I click on a news link... but the news exist!

I totally reboot safari on my macbook and now, it's true, it doesn't work anymore

I'm not a programmer, just a self-educated guy who tries to progress so please be patient!
Every kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your friend an olympic medal winner? that's pretty cool. Do you recieve any errors in your safari javascript console - and have you tested this in chrome (i.e is this a webkit issue or safari specifically)

Comment: Hi, yes Marie is more than a friend, she's a cousin of my wife ;) I've tested with chrome, no problem... I'll get a look for errors in javascript console and let you know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Please send the URL from the page while it is open in safari.** (I think it is like that because of the ugly URL but I can say more if you give me the URL --- I don't have Safari on my Ubuntu)

*You included the css of jScrollPane on the Homepage which doesen't exists.*

*Try to use minified versions of javascript and css (it takes hours until the page finished loading) (http://jscompress.com/, http://www.minifyjavascript.com/, http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html, http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/)*

*If you type a wrong news url, the site is schown with the black box in the middle but without any text. Try to create a error page*